# How to enable ZipArchive PHP class

Tags: php, zip, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux, amazon

Recently I have installed a PHP on Amazon Linux to run Chevereto. It's an image hosting service.

When I wanted to install it on my EC2 instance, I got the following error:

> Aw, Snap! Your web server lacks some requirements that must be fixed to install Chevereto. Please check: 
>   **Enable ZipArchive PHP class**

Does anyone know how to enable this on Amazon Linux?

Comment: Would depend on how it is installed (package manager vs. binary download vs building source) and how the PHP extensions are managed (Debian has `phpenmod` etc).  Quick google shows Amazon's distro uses `yum` for package management, so I'd guess it is similar to redhat or fedora and instructions for those distros would probably work.